# On-topic question closed because it is "off-topic"

Tags: discussion

Recently, I asked something about emulators at *Arqade* ( [post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/264229/134868) ). Also, in the comments I asked why I got downvoted, and then, someone said because people think I'm asking something that's off-topic when it isn't. Another user commented why my post is on-topic refeering into another post (see comments of my post).

Also, when I tap over the exclamation mark, I read the post has been put on hold as off-topic because I'm speaking something about *unrelased or illegal* things, when I am not speaking any type of game.

After two days, my question **got closed because it is off-topic.**

- Why my post got closed (and why people with high reputation doesn't know how to differenciate between off-topic and on-topic?)?
- Can my post be putted as on-topic again?

Comment: I don't think it's a good question, and have downvoted, but I do believe it's on-topic, so I've voted to reopen.

Comment: I assume people saw the mention of emulators which can often be used for piracy, and that's why it got the illegal things close reason, because we don't want to get in the habit of supporting pirated things. That said, emulation itself isn't off-topic. I'm not guaranteeing you will get an answer if it is reopened, but I see no reason for it not to be.

Comment: @AshleyNunn - Emulation isn't off topic because emulation isn't illegal. (I also answered it two days ago :) )

Comment: @robotnik I know it isn't. :)  I just know people tend to lump it in with piracy stuff.